# Fan clutch on 3500 duramax

Tags: chevrolet, fan, water-pump, pulley

I’m replacing the water pump on a 2005 3500 duramax. How can I remove the fan clutch?
I’ve tried the wrench and clutch tool, an air hammer on the bolt, and a rod and hammer on the bolt. I’ve also tried penetrating oil and it still won’t budge. 
It’s a 47mm right hand thread.

Comment: [Try these methodries?](https://youtu.be/k0xKWn1lz1I)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yes. The wire and coat hanger both broke.

Comment: [See if this might help you.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/29467/4152) While not your engine, it is a way to hold the pulley ... and let me tell you, done right, it will hold it tight.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 my belt slips too much but definitely an interesting method

Comment: If the belt slips, you don't have it on there tight enough.

Comment: Just tried a ratchet strap to a bolt that I had in the pulley. Strapped the other end to a low point on my car, which snapped the strap. I might have to break it off

Comment: This is the tool I use, has never failed me yet.....https://www.amazon.com/Lisle-43300-Pneumatic-Clutch-Wrench/dp/B000JFJLTC

Comment: A ratchet strap is feeble unless it is one of the truck sized towing ones...

Comment: There's a fairly large difference between a ratchet strap and a serpentine belt as far as holding power. I had an alternator seize up on my Chevy 350 V8 in my Suburban once. Just killed the engine straight out. There is *a lot* of staying power on the serpentine belt, especially if you loop it over a secondary pulley to hold it in place.